# R Barplot of Matrix and characters

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am new to R, trying to learn as much as possible, but can't claim to know much at this point!

I am trying to plot the **`outcome`**, in respect of each **`time`** number from the matrix of data I have below.

```
no. time    outcome
1   7   win
2   7   win
3   8   win
4   8   lose
5   8   draw
6   10  win
7   10  win
8   10  lose
9   10  win
10  10  draw
```

So for example, for any given time, I would like to use barplot to show bars for the amount of `win`,`lose`, or `draw` occurrences.

I have sort of done this by creating a subset based on **`time`**, then creating a vector of the **`outcome`**, then making a table of the vector, and then plotting the table against a vector of numbers for the height.

Sorry, I can't post images, but anyway, the above works, but only for one given **`time`**. I would like to show the occurrences for all times.

I'd greatly appreciate some help if possible, even if just a point in the direction of useful reading material!

Comment: can you please post your code that worked for one given time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is easy with `ggplot2`:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "no. time    outcome
1   7   win
2   7   win
3   8   win
4   8   lose
5   8   draw
6   10  win
7   10  win
8   10  lose
9   10  win
10  10  draw", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.factor(time), fill = outcome)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "bin")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sven, that is impressive and a lot more straightforward than my efforts! Much appreciated.

Comment: Could I be cheeky and ask how to have a bar for each outcome type. So there would be three bars for each instance of time?

Comment: @user3316115 You can try `ggplot(dat, aes(x = as.factor(time), fill = outcome)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")`.